# jQuery: How to edit appended input value in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, input, save, append, edit

I have some input values on the left (let's call it the input panel). When the addbutton is clicked, these input values are appended to the sidebar on the right in a div called bluebox

here is a jsfiddle from the above: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/s6Yxz/)

Now I want the user to be able to click on one of the divs and edit the appended input value's and keep the changes. I prefer the inputs to appear in the input panel again but than with a 'save/keep changes button'

I thought of some ways to do this, but am a beginner so could be terribly wrong ;) :

**Example 1**

- Make the bluebox div classes clickable like this: `$(".bluebox").click(function(){}`
- Instead of using .html I should append the values from the inputpanel to each it's own input label

What do you suggest as a solution for my goal? 
And why will my example work or fail?

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: html5 contenteditor http://html5demos.com/contenteditable

Comment: If you don't want to use HTML5 `contenteditable`, you'll have to bind a function to the click event where it replaces the existing elements with the form to edit them and have a save button on that which saves and replaces the form with the non-editable elements.

Comment: Direction you are heading is manageable, but back up one step and get firm grasp on using delegation methods for future elements. Current code calls `live()` inside the `addbutton` clcik. This will keep adding handlers to the elements already added. Add 5 elements, the first element will trigger it's click handler 5 times when clicked. There are also editable plugins that can make it easier for you

Answer (score 2):

I suggest that you add a save button, a hidden blueboxid div that keeps track of which bluebox was clicked, and a slightly more modular design so that you can account for changes more easily (and also make things easier to read).

I have a finished jsfiddle here for you http://jsfiddle.net/s6Yxz/26/ :)

Comment: Nice.  I'd probably still use data attributes instead of classes, but whatever .. +1

Comment: @Rey Gonzales: Thank you for your explanation and solution. I'm gonna try some stuff out for myself, see if I understand everything so I'll get back on it!

Answer (score 1):

A couple of general ideas - you could add data to the bluebox div like so:

```
$('<div>').addClass('bluebox').data({ field1: field1.val(), /* field 2 etc.. */ });
```

Then retrieve the values like:

```
$('.bluebox').click(function() {
  field1.val( $(this).data('field1') );
  // field 2 etc..
});
```

Or you could create a structure of spans within the bluebox:

```
bluebox = $('<div>').addClass('bluebox');
bluebox.append($('<span>').attr('data-name', 'field1').text(field1.val()));
// field 2 etc..
```

Then retrieve the values like:

```
$('.bluebox').click(function() {
  field1.val( $(this).find('span[data-name=field1]').text() );
  // field 2 etc..
});
```

As this gets more complex, you might want to use a loop over the field names with cases for different types of fields.

Comment: Thank you for your explanations and ideas, I'll give it all a go and see if I understand everything :) to be continued..

Answer (score -1):

If **add-it** button is not posting the data to server, you can use an inline editor on the `.bluebox` and finally with a **save-it** button you can post the data in `#sidebar` to server.